# WooCommerce new account email comes with multiple header footer loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-email

I am importing some users using `wp_insert_user` function. I am trying to send WooCommerce new account email, when user is successfully imported.
It works fine, when there is only one user. But if there are multiple users, the email comes with multiple header and footer loop!

This is what the email looks like, when I am importing four users:
[image]

This is how my code looks like:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata[$user] );
    $wc = new WC_Emails();
    $wc->customer_new_account( $user_id, null, true );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata[$user] );
    global $woocommerce;
    $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();
    $mailer->customer_new_account( $user_id, null, true );
}
```

Try like this

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. Also moving `$wc = new WC_Emails();` out of foreach loop solved the issue for me.